# Tools to format XML in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: xml, visual-studio, xaml, vsix, xml-formatting

Is there an XML formatter available as an add-in for Visual Studio 2010? I am currently using Notepad++ and using the XML Tools plug-in to get the formatting sorted.

Is there an add-in for VS2010, which will do something similar?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Simply press `Ctrl+E,D` or use the following command from the menu:

*Edit -> Advanced -> Format Document*

Answer (score 2):

In my version of VS 2010 it's **Ctrl+K,D**

or

**Edit -> Format Document**

Answer (score 1):

Personally these days **I couldn't survive without**

1. "**Align Attributes each on a separate line**"

> Found in standard VS options :
>
> ```
>         Tools > Options > XML > Formatting
> ```

2. The ***fantastic* [XAML Regions](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3c534623-bb05-417f-afc0-c9e26bf0e177) Extension**

> Which also works for straight XML, adding the ability to create collapsible regions similar to the following (in c#) :

```
#region 

public void SomeMethod()
{
//...
}

#endregion
```

Comment: my 2010 has it in
Tools > Options > Text Editor > XML > Formatting